# Looking for example of non-elliptical, multivariate, absolutely continuous distributions with non independent components

Tags: multivariate-analysis, simulation

I would like to test several (multivariate --between 5 and 20 dimensions) depth measures empirically. I'm looking for a couple of test-benches (read distributions). These should be:

1. non-elliptical,
2. absolutely continuous,
3. uni-modal
4. have convex contours (if you prefer, level sets)
5. have non independent components.
6. Easy to implement (i.e. implemented in R or source code available on-line).
7. defined in arbitrary dimensions

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29) might be a good starting point. [R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html) and [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/stats/copulademo.html) packages are available for common types.

Comment: aren't they mostly bivariate (except for the trivial ones)? I need the number of variables to be in the 5 to 20 range.

Comment: Copulas can have as many dimensions as you like, the examples are bivariate because it's easy to visualize.

Comment: The examples i have seen in the copula package in R are limited to 6-10 dimensions. Can you suggest another package?